# how to encrypt css/js filename

Tags: javascript, html, css, encryption

Is there a way to encrypt the filename of the css/js file? I notice that when I view source the website, the filename of the css and js files are encrypted like this.

```
<link href="/assets/css/builds/73e15c8a3cf6409214bbf8a742e9b5d41403226617.css" rel="stylesheet">

<script src="/assets/js/builds/217651bd25211390d62315e92b525f667014020626.js"></script>
```

Is there a script to do so?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Most likely part of their deployment system to combat caching issues when their JS or CSS changes; the hash is probably the `sha1()` of its respective file contents. Definitely **not** related to security at all.

Comment: I see.. Do you happen to know a tool that does this? Is this something like Cloudflare? (well, cloudflare minifies the html/js/css.. dont know if it does this one too)

Comment: Can't speak for other developers, but I've written a tool such as this one myself; it combines and minifies multiple scripts together and then use a hash function to generate the file name before it's uploaded onto a CDN. Code and style changes would be near immediate.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is typically part of a deployment step that aims to:

1. reduce the number of requests by combining all scripts/styles on a single page together.
2. minify the combined scripts/styles (optional, but recommended)
3. avoid unintentional cache hits if you make changes to the scripts/styles.

**It does not add security in any way**

Once the combined scripts/styles have been built, the contents is typically hashed using either md5() or sha1() and that hash becomes part of the file name; it provides a unique filename as well as prevent cache misses if the files didn't change.

I'm not aware of generic tools that perform this for you; I've written one for my own purposes, though, it's not rocket science after all.

Comment: this really interest me :)

Answer (score 1):

Well, you could run an ordinary filename through a cryptographic hash function like MD5 (which should still be OK for something like this, but which has known weaknesses for use in digital signatures.)

If you run "standard" as in "standard.css" through MD5 using the tool at http://www.fileformat.info/tool/hash.htm you get `c00f0c4675b91fb8b918e4079a0b1bac`.  I'm not sure what this buys one, other than to obscure a name.

Edited to echo Jack's comment that you haven't really protected anything, just obscured a name, which is likely to make things harder on you, rather than on others!

Comment: Running the file name itself through a hashing function would be silly; the hashing should be applied to the file contents and *that* forms the file name.

Comment: Correct, if what one wants to do is auto-generate a new file name when the file content changes.  If the only objective is to obscure the file name, then MD5 or SHA-1 will do it.  As you say, that doesn't add any protection, just obfuscation.